# why use call back function if one function can call another?

Tags: callback

The following code is an example of using function callbacks. I don't understand why function callback is required as one function could call another function.

```
int absolute_compare(int a , int b)   // callback function


{
 if (abs(a)>abs(b)) return -1;
 else
 return 1;
}

void sort(int *A, int size, int(*Ab_compare)(int, int))

{
int i,j,temp;
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
for (j=0;j<size-1;j++)
{
if (Ab_compare(A[j],A[j+1])>0)
 {
   temp=A[j];
   A[j]=A[j+1];
   A[j+1]=temp;
  }
 }
}
int main()
{

int A[]={1,7,-5,8,-67,45,34,89,23,-11,2,-8,4};
int size,i;
size=sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
sort(A,size,absolute_compare);
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
 printf("%d   ",A[i]);
}
printf("\n.......\n");
return 0;
}
```

As sort() function could call Absolute_compare(), why passing Absolute_compare() to sort() as argument and then call Absolute_compare()?

Comment: Well imagine you wanted to sort in a different way. Does it make sense to have to rewrite or create a whole new sort function to call a new comparator, or to just pass a different comparator in?

Comment: Or imagine `sort` was provided by a 3rd party library that has been written by someone else and they know nothing about your `absolute_compare`

Comment: Passing comparator as callback function or calling the comparator, Either way you have to use different comparator for sorting in different way. My question was why use callback if you could call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to support various callback functions - you might need another comparison function (I can't think of any other that direct comparison for integers), and you will not have to implement another sorter function.